# AVURLAsset (MP3) showing no audio tracks

Tags: objective-c, ios11, xcode9, avurlasset

I am trying to set an mp3 as the audio track of a video.  However, I am finding no tracks in the AVURLAsset.  This mp3 is in my project so it is a local file.

My code is below, I have also tried to get any tracks but that comes back out of range as well.

```
AVURLAsset *blank = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSBundle.mainBundle pathForResource:@"empty" ofType:@"mp3"]] options:nil];
if (blank != nil)
{
    // Out of range error occurs here.
    AVAssetTrack *tmp = [blank tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio][0];

    [audioTrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, tmp.duration) ofTrack:tmp atTime:kCMTimeZero error:nil];
}
```

What am I missing?  I do the same type of procedure with video files without issue.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**UPDATE**

After some research I found that the tracks might not be loaded yet and I could request to load them.  I tried that with the same results :(

I also tried a different MP3 and a WAV file with the same result as well!  HELP!!!!

```
AVURLAsset *blank = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSBundle.mainBundle pathForResource:@"empty" ofType:@"mp3"]] options:nil];
                //AVURLAsset *blank = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSBundle.mainBundle pathForResource:@"0917" ofType:@"wav"]] options:nil];
                if (blank != nil)
                {
                    if ([blank isPlayable])
                    {
                        mediaReady = NO;
                        NSString *tracksKey = @"tracks";

                        [blank loadValuesAsynchronouslyForKeys:@[tracksKey] completionHandler:
                         ^{
                             NSError *error;
                             AVKeyValueStatus status = [blank statusOfValueForKey:tracksKey error:&error];
                             if (status == AVKeyValueStatusLoaded) {
                                 // The asset is ready at this point
                                 NSArray *tmp = [blank tracks];
                                 //NSArray *tmp = [blank tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio];

                                 if ([tmp count])
                                 {
                                     [audioTrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, Asset1.duration) ofTrack:[tmp objectAtIndex:0] atTime:kCMTimeZero error:nil];
                                 }

                             }
                             mediaReady = YES;
                         }];

                        while (!mediaReady)
                        {
                            NSLog(@"Waiting...");
                            [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.5f];
                        }
                    }

                }

                else
                {
                    NSLog(@"Not Playable");
                }
```

Comment: I also have no tracks on a AVURLAsset

Comment: did you find a solution?